# How use the newton function for root finding of the Scipy's optimize package

Tags: python, scipy

I want to use the `newton` function loaded as

```
from scipy.optimize import newton
```

in order to find the zeros of a function enetered by the user. I write a script that first ask to the user to specify a function together with its first derivative, and also the starting point of the algorithm. First of all typing `help(newton)` I saw which parameters takes the function and the relative explanation:

`newton(func, x0, fprime=None, args=(), tol=1.48e-08, maxiter=50)`

```
func : function
    The function whose zero is wanted. It must be a function of a
    single variable of the form f(x,a,b,c...), where a,b,c... are extra
    arguments that can be passed in the `args` parameter.
```

In which way I have to pass my function? If I use for func e.g. `x**3` (and its first derivative) the response is `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`. On the internet I find that first I have to define my function and its first derivative and pass the names as parameters. So I made the following

```
fie = raw_input('Enter function in terms of x (e.g. x**2 - 2*x). F= ')
dfie = raw_input('Enter first derivative of function above DF = ')
x0 = input('Enter starting point x0 = ')

def F(x,fie):
    y = eval(fie)
    return y 

def DF(x, dfie):
    dy = eval(dfie)
    return dy

print newton(F,x0,DF)
```

But I get the output

```
    102         for iter in range(maxiter):
    103             myargs = (p0,) + args
--> 104             fder = fprime(*myargs)
    105             if fder == 0:
    106                 msg = "derivative was zero."

TypeError: DF() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

and the same issue for `F` if I omit `DF`. Looking at the code in `/usr/local/share/src/scipy/scipy/optimize/zeros.py` I see that it evaluates the first derivative with `fder=fprime(*myargs)` so maybe I have to put in `args` something that make it working. I was thinking about it but no solution comes to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, be aware that using `eval` makes your program vulnerable to malicious users. If that concern does not apply, you can create F and DF like this:

```
F = eval('lambda x :'+fie)
DF = eval('lambda x :'+dfie)
```

Then both functions expect only a single argument, and you can leave the `args` argument empty.

EDIT. If you really want to stick to your code as closely as possible, this should also work, but it does not look very nice to me. `newton` will send the same `args` to both functions.

```
def F(x,fie,dfie):
    y = eval(fie)
    return y 

def DF(x,fie,dfie):
    dy = eval(dfie)
    return dy

print newton(F,x0,DF,(fie,dfie))
```

Comment: Sorry but this is uclear for me (the lambda I mean), could you explain me such "formaism"?

Comment: @StefanoMessina A [lambda expression](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms) evaluates to a function object.

Comment: Let's say for a moment that I "have to" use parameter 'args' of function newton() to pass 'fie'.

Comment: @StefanoMessina Added such an approach to my answer.